# Help in Tikz, line overlapping

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

i got the following code from another side. How is it possible to not overlap the lines and points?

```
\documentclass[ 
  fontsize=12pt, 
  twoside, 
  open=right, 
  toc=bibnumbered, 
  toc=listof, 
  captions=abovetable,% <- ergänzt
  ngerman 
]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\newcommand\zeilenabstand{10pt} 

\tikzset{vp/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}} 
\newcommand\verbindungslinie[3]{ 
  \node[#1,vp]at([yshift=-.15*\zeilenabstand]#2.south){};
  \foreach [remember=\p as \lastp (initially #2)] \p in {#3} 
    \draw[ultra thick,#1,draw opacity=.4]([yshift=-.15*\zeilenabstand]\lastp.south)--([yshift=-.15*\zeilenabstand]\p.south)node[vp]{}; 
} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{center} 
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth} 
    \captionof{table}{Morphologischer Kasten Getriebevarianten}\label{morphologischer_kasten} 
    
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \matrix[ 
          matrix of nodes ,
          inner sep=0pt,
          row sep=\zeilenabstand,
          column sep=15pt,
          nodes={font=\strut},
          nodes in empty cells,
          column 2/.style={text width=5cm}, 
          column 3/.style={text width=3.5cm,align=center}, 
          column 4/.style={text width=3.5cm,align=center}, 
          column 5/.style={text width=3.5cm,align=center}
       ](m) 
       { 
           1& Übertragung 
            & Schneckenradsatz 
            & Innenradpaarung
            & Strinradpaarung\\ 
           2& Schmierung 
            & Tauchschmierung 
            & Trockenschmierung 
            & Sprühschmierung\\ 
           3& Gesamtgröße 
            & Klein 
            & Mittel 
            & Groß\\ 
           4& Kleiner Durchlass
            & Ja 
            & Nein 
            &\\ 
            &&&&\\
            &
            &|[red]|{\textbf{LV1}}
            &|[blue]|{\textbf{LV2}}
            &|[green]|{\textbf{LV3}}\\ 
        }; 
% Kopfzeile 
        \node(ul)[anchor=south west] 
          at ([yshift={\zeilenabstand+\aboverulesep+\belowrulesep}]m.north west) 
          {Teilfunktion}; 
        \node(or)[anchor=south east] at (ul.north-|m-1-2.east){Lösungsvarianten}; 
        \foreach[count=\i from 3] \l in {1,2,3} 
          \node[anchor=base] at (or.base-|m-1-\i){\l}; 
% Tabellenlinien 
        \draw[line width=\lightrulewidth](or.north-|ul.west)--(or.east|-ul.south) 
          ([yshift=-\aboverulesep]ul.south-|m.west) 
            --([yshift=-\aboverulesep]ul.south-|m.east); 
        \draw[line width=\heavyrulewidth]([yshift=\belowrulesep]or.north-|m.west) 
            --([yshift=\belowrulesep]or.north-|m.east) 
          ([yshift={-\aboverulesep}]m.south west) 
            --([yshift={-\aboverulesep}]m.south east); 
% Verbindungslinien 
        \verbindungslinie{red}{m-1-3}{m-2-3,m-3-3,m-4-3,m-5-3} 
        \verbindungslinie{blue}{m-1-4}{m-2-4,m-3-4,m-4-3,m-4-4,m-5-4} 
        \verbindungslinie{green}{m-1-5}{m-2-4,m-3-4,m-4-4,m-5-5} 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
  \end{minipage} 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I Ti*k*Z, what you draw later will overlap what you draw frist. But you can make use of the [`background` library](https://tikz.dev/library-backgrounds). Just load `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` after loading `tikz` and then put all the drawing commands (including you custom `\verbindungslinie` command) inside a scope, that is between `\begin{scope}[on background layer]` and `\end{scope}`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Tried it but the overview is the same like before. Do you know a solution to line up the points?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not get what you want to achieve. My suggestion was to place the lines in the background. The text will then be typset before the lines, but of course the lines will still be at the same position. If this is not what you aim for, maybe try to better explain what the issue is.

Comment: Maybe I get what you want: You want the differently colored dots to be positioned next to each other?

Comment: maybe a hand sketch of the desired output would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me what exactly you want to achieve. But maybe you want automatically shift the nodes so that two nodes in the same cell do not overlap each other. You could achieve this with the following approach:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, backgrounds} 

\newcommand\zeilenabstand{10pt} 

\def\GetNodeColumn(#1-#2-#3){#3}

\tikzset{vp/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=2pt}} 
\newcommand\verbindungslinie[4][10pt]{ 
  \node[#2, vp] at ([yshift=-.15*\zeilenabstand]#3.south) {};
  \edef\co{\noexpand\GetNodeColumn(#3)}
  \foreach[remember=\p as \lastp (initially #3)] \p in {#4} 
    \edef\cl{\noexpand\GetNodeColumn(\lastp)}
    \edef\cp{\noexpand\GetNodeColumn(\p)}
    \draw[ultra thick, #2, draw opacity=.4]
        ([yshift=-.15*\zeilenabstand,xshift={#1*(\co-\cl)}]\lastp.south) -- 
        ([yshift=-.15*\zeilenabstand,xshift={#1*(\co-\cp)}]\p.south) 
        node[vp] {}; 
} 

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \matrix[ 
          matrix of nodes,
          inner sep=0pt,
          row sep=\zeilenabstand,
          column sep=15pt,
          nodes={font=\strut},
          nodes in empty cells,
          column 2/.style={text width=5cm}, 
          column 3/.style={text width=3.5cm,align=center}, 
          column 4/.style={text width=3.5cm,align=center}, 
          column 5/.style={text width=3.5cm,align=center}
       ](m) 
       { 
          1 & Übertragung 
            & Schneckenradsatz 
            & Innenradpaarung
            & Strinradpaarung\\ 
          2 & Schmierung 
            & Tauchschmierung 
            & Trockenschmierung 
            & Sprühschmierung\\ 
          3 & Gesamtgröße 
            & Klein 
            & Mittel 
            & Groß\\ 
          4 & Kleiner Durchlass
            & Ja 
            & Nein 
            &\\ 
            &&&&\\
            &
            &|[red]|{\textbf{LV1}}
            &|[blue]|{\textbf{LV2}}
            &|[green]|{\textbf{LV3}}\\ 
        }; 
% Kopfzeile 
        \node(ul)[anchor=south west] 
          at ([yshift={\zeilenabstand+\aboverulesep+\belowrulesep}]m.north west) 
          {Teilfunktion}; 
        \node(or)[anchor=south east] at (ul.north-|m-1-2.east){Lösungsvarianten}; 
        \foreach[count=\i from 3] \l in {1,2,3} 
          \node[anchor=base] at (or.base-|m-1-\i){\l}; 
% Tabellenlinien 
        \draw[line width=\lightrulewidth](or.north-|ul.west)--(or.east|-ul.south) 
          ([yshift=-\aboverulesep]ul.south-|m.west) 
            --([yshift=-\aboverulesep]ul.south-|m.east); 
        \draw[line width=\heavyrulewidth]([yshift=\belowrulesep]or.north-|m.west) 
            --([yshift=\belowrulesep]or.north-|m.east) 
          ([yshift={-\aboverulesep}]m.south west) 
            --([yshift={-\aboverulesep}]m.south east); 
% Verbindungslinien 
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
          \verbindungslinie{red}{m-1-3}{m-2-4,m-3-3,m-4-3,m-5-3} 
          \verbindungslinie{blue}{m-1-4}{m-2-4,m-3-4,m-4-3,m-5-3} 
          \verbindungslinie{green}{m-1-5}{m-2-4,m-3-4,m-4-4,m-5-3} 
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed the position of some dots in your original drawing to show that dots will be shifted in both directions depending on whether they are shifted to the right or to the left and they will be shifted more if the distance is larger.

The shifting won't happen for the first dot in the row. You can change the distance of the shift by setting an optional parameter such as `\verbindungslinie[10pt]{red}{m-1-3}{m-2-4,m-3-3,m-4-3,m-5-3}`.

Finally I placed all the lines behind the text using the `backgrounds` library.